# Can we change the "Solstice" tag to the "David Lively" tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

18 of the 19 questions tagged "Solstice" are his solstice.  Assuming we can't outright change it (after all, how would future solstice enthusiasts find solstice related questions?) could we get some kind of "Solstice of Sorrow" or "Guess who's back; back again" tag going?

My thought is that it adds a fun little tag for this legendary little car, so that future readers can stumble upon, and be awed by, the epic tale. But on the other hand stack isn't exactly about "fun"

Thoughts?

Comment: +1 Works for me! I have my own dedicated car thread on the solstice forum. http://www.solsticeforum.com/forum/f11/junker-s-thread-141145/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[solstice-of-sorrow](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/solstice-of-sorrow) it is. (Who said we can't have a little fun?)